# Why do I get an extra 0 on my script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, grep

I don't know why I get an extra `0` when I run my script.

This is my script: I run a SQL query and save it ta an file `valor.txt`.

This is my array: `array=(50 60 70)`

`Valor.txt`:

```
 count | trn_hst_id | trn_msg_host
-------+------------+--------------
    11 |         50 | Aprobada
     2 |         70 | Aprobada
(2 rows)
```

Code:

```
function service_status {
    cd
    cat valor.txt | grep $1 | gawk '{print $1}' FS="|" | sed "s/ //g"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -n 0
        else
        echo -n $1
    fi
}

        echo "<prtg>"

# <-- Start
        for i in "${array[@]}"
        do

        echo -n "   <result>
       <channel>$i</channel>
       <value>"
        service_status $i
        echo "</value>
       </result>"
       done
# End -->
       echo "</prtg>"
       exit
```

And this is my output.

```html
<prtg>
   <result>
       <channel>50</channel>
       <value>11
0</value>
       </result>
   <result>
       <channel>60</channel>
       <value>0</value>
       </result>
   <result>
       <channel>70</channel>
       <value>2
0</value>
       </result>
</prtg>
```

Why do I get the `0` here? —

```
       <value>2
0</value>
```

Comment: What are the values in `array`? What's inside `valor.txt`? Presumably, your pipeline is producing a value, then you're doing `echo -n 0`.

Comment: I think it is the output of `cat valor.txt | grep $1 | gawk '{print $1}' FS="|" | sed "s/ //g"`.  Not sure why you have that command sequence and then also have `echo` statements based on `$?`.

Comment: @TomFenech sorry,  now its up

Comment: @cxw yes im getting the correct outoput and im trying to put the count of trn_hst_id on the value TAG   but when the value <> 0  i always get the a 0 value after the correct result

Comment: Thanks - I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42400456/2877364) will work.  You are actually _always_ getting a 0 - the `<value>0</value>` for `60` comes from the `if` statement. :)

Comment: `sed` will return 0 even if nothing matched. The only time `sed` returns non zero is when something wrong happens, such as file access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your comment correctly, you want to print the count.  That is the value of the `count` column, if present in `valor.txt`, or 0 if the `trn_hst_id` in `array` is not in `valor.txt`.  This should work (though not tested):

```
function service_status {
    val=$(cat ~/valor.txt | grep $1 | gawk '{print $1}' FS="|" | sed "s/ //g")
        #     ^^ so you don't need to "cd" each time
        # Save the value into "$val"
    echo -n "${val:-0}"     # If there is nothing in $val, print a 0
}
```

The `"${val:-0}"` sequence expands as `"$val"`, if `$val` has text in it, or as a literal `0` otherwise.  If the `$1` wasn't in `valor.txt`, `$val` will be empty, so you will get a zero.  See [the wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) for more about how `:-` and friends work.

Answer (score 1):

The "0" is the result of the `echo -n 0` which is executed inside the function in case the `awk` command works properly (which is usually the case).
From the code it is not clear why is it written like it is. It's clear that is supposed to extract certain values from a file, but the 'if' condition seems to be checking the wrong thing, the return code of 'sed' which I bet is not what is intended. (better candidate would be the return code of 'grep'.

So I would write the function like this:

```
function service_status {
    cd
    var=$(cat valor.txt | grep $1 | gawk '{print $1}' FS="|" | sed "s/ //g")
    if [ -z "$var" ]; then
        echo -n 0
    else
        echo -n "$var"
    fi
}
```

The variable 'var' will contain the result of the "search command". If the search would not return any value then 'var' will be empty and '0' will be the output of the function, otherwise the content of 'var' will be on the output.